# Exception handling around "instanceof" operation in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, instanceof

"**instanceof**" operator is supposed to check whether an Object matches a class type. It should return true/false based on the match. But sometime when a match doesn't happen, it throws an Error (instead of returning False) e.g

`boolean f = "hello" instanceof BigInteger;`

this actually throws an error:

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to BigInteger
```

So, should we surround instanceof operations with try-catch blocks? If we should, then what's the purpose of instanceof.

Comment: This is a *compiler* error, because it can never work. A `String` is not "related" to a `BigInteger`

Comment: *"So, should we surround instanceof operations with try-catch blocks?"*  - You cannot "catch" a compilation error.